# Invalid Identifier error in MERGE statement - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I'm trying to use a `MERGE` statement in PL/SQL, but I'm having the Invalid Identifier error.

```
merge into t082assdetail t082
using (select * 
     from t082assdetail t082
     inner join t080assortment t080
     on t082.codassortment = t080.codassortment and t082.coddiv = t080.coddiv
     inner join tz084custcat tz084
     on t080.z_codbanner = tz084.z_codbanner and t080.codassortmenttype = tz084.codassortmenttype and t080.coddiv = tz084.coddiv
     and t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = t084.z_custcodassortmenttype) a
on (t082.codassortment = a.codassortment and t082.coddiv = a.coddiv and t082.prgassortment = a.prgassortment and t082.codart = a.codart
    and t082.numprg = a.numprg and t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = a.custcodassortmenttype)
when matched then update set t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = a.zcustcodassortmenttype
```

This is the full query, and the error is triggered on `a.prgassortment`. I believe the thing is the alias used in the `USING` clause is not recognized outside, but I can't seem to find a way to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initially get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "T084"."Z_CUSTCODASSORTMENTTYPE": invalid identifier
> ```

This is because the table alias is `tz084` not `t084`.

Once you fix that, you get error:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "A"."Z_CUSTCODASSORTMENTTYPE": invalid identifier
> ```

This is because you use `SELECT *` and there are multiple columns with the identical identifiers across the tables you are joining; instead explicitly name the columns to select so there are no duplicate identifiers:

```sql
merge into t082assdetail t082
using (
  select t082.codassortment,
         t082.coddiv,
         t082.prgassortment,
         t082.codart,
         t082.numprg,
         t082.z_custcodassortmenttype
  from   t082assdetail t082
         inner join t080assortment t080
         on t082.codassortment = t080.codassortment
            and t082.coddiv = t080.coddiv
         inner join tz084custcat tz084
         on t080.z_codbanner = tz084.z_codbanner
            and t080.codassortmenttype = tz084.codassortmenttype
            and t080.coddiv = tz084.coddiv
            and t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = tz084.z_custcodassortmenttype
) a
on (   t082.codassortment = a.codassortment
   and t082.coddiv = a.coddiv
   and t082.prgassortment = a.prgassortment
   and t082.codart = a.codart
   and t082.numprg = a.numprg
   and t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = a.z_custcodassortmenttype
   )
when matched then
  update
  set t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = a.z_custcodassortmenttype
```

Then you will get the error:

> ```
> ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "T082"."Z_CUSTCODASSORTMENTTYPE"
> ```

You need to not use `"T082"."Z_CUSTCODASSORTMENTTYPE"` in the `ON` clause but this is not something that we can tell you how to fix as you need to work out what else you can join the tables on.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yAr4wAeW)

Comment: This was right on point, thank you so much! I've managed to fix the ON clause as that field wasn't really necessary

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that asterisk is the culprit, because it selected all columns from all tables involved. Regarding `JOIN`s which *match* columns with the same name - for example

```
and t082.z_custcodassortmenttype = t084.z_custcodassortmenttype     --> two z_custcodassortmenttype columns
```

it means that `select` also returned

```
select t082.z_custcodassortmenttype, t084.z_custcodassortmenttype   --> two z_custcodassortmenttype   columns
```

and - when you tried to update target table's `z_custcodassortmenttype` column, which one - of these two - will you take? Sure, they match, but there's ambiguity in that.

Here's an example: I want to populate `T_EMP.DNAME` column value from the `DEPT` table:

```
SQL> select * from t_emp;

    DEPTNO ENAME      DNAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
        20 SMITH
        20 JONES
        10 CLARK
        20 SCOTT
        10 KING
        20 ADAMS
        20 FORD
        10 MILLER

8 rows selected.

SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

`merge` with an asterisk (line #2) raises error you mentioned:

```
SQL> merge into t_emp a
  2    using (select *
  3           from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  4          ) x
  5    on (a.deptno = x.deptno)
  6    when matched then update set
  7      a.dname = x.dname;
  on (a.deptno = x.deptno)
                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00904: "X"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier
```

But, if you explicitly state columns involved, query works:

```
SQL> merge into t_emp a
  2    using (select distinct d.deptno, d.dname
  3           from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  4          ) x
  5    on (a.deptno = x.deptno)
  6    when matched then update set
  7      a.dname = x.dname;

8 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From t_emp;

    DEPTNO ENAME      DNAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
        20 SMITH      RESEARCH
        20 JONES      RESEARCH
        10 CLARK      ACCOUNTING
        20 SCOTT      RESEARCH
        10 KING       ACCOUNTING
        20 ADAMS      RESEARCH
        20 FORD       RESEARCH
        10 MILLER     ACCOUNTING

8 rows selected.
```